# JAR's signer information conflict with another class

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, jar, aws-glue

I'm trying to load two jars into my AWS Glue/Spark read method but got an error:

```
An error occurred while calling o142.save.
: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ISQLServerBulkData"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
    at java.security.SecureClas...
```

My code below, I tried multiple glue_dynamicFrame `write` methods but bulk insert into SQL erver is not working. According to MS these drivers should do the trick.

Any suggestions on fixing it are highly welcomed!

```
def write_df_to_target(self, df, schema_table):
    spark = self.gc.spark_session
    spark.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0').getOrCreate()
    credentials = self.get_credentials(self.replica_connection_name)

    df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", credentials["url"] + ";databaseName=" + self.database_name) \
        .option("dbtable", schema_table) \
        .option("user", credentials["user"]) \
        .option("password", credentials["password"]) \
        .option("batchsize","50000") \
        .option("numPartitions","150") \
        .option("bulkCopyTableLock","true") \
        .save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` is one thing but also you need proper version of [MS' Spark SQL Connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector)

`com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha` and `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` did not work for my case as I'm using AWS Glue 3.0 (which is Spark 3.1)

I had to switch to `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0` as it's Spark 3.1 compatible.

```
def write_df_to_target(self, df, schema_table):
    spark = self.gc.spark_session
    spark.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0').getOrCreate()
    credentials = self.get_credentials(self.replica_connection_name)

    df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", credentials["url"] + ";databaseName=" + self.database_name) \
        .option("dbtable", schema_table) \
        .option("user", credentials["user"]) \
        .option("password", credentials["password"]) \
        .option("batchsize","100000") \
        .option("numPartitions","15") \
        .save()
```